# Merge specific key values of two dictionaries where id matches in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with two array of JSON objects in Angular, both the dictionaries have "song_id" as similar key-value.
I want to merge the "rating" key-value with the first array where the song_id matches.

Original Array 1:

```
this.Array1 = [
  {"song_id": 01, "artist_name": "Arijit, Shreya", "song_name": "Song1"},
  {"song_id": 02,"artist_name": "Jason, Ankit", "song_name": "Song2"},
  {"song_id": 03,"artist_name": "Asha, Lata, Bapi", "song_name": "Song3"},
]
```

Original Array 2:

```
this.Array2 = [
  {"song_id": 01, "user_id": 5, "rating": 4},
  {"song_id": 02, "user_id": 5, "rating": 5},
  {"song_id": 03, "user_id": 5, "rating": 3},
]
```

Expected Result:

```
this.Array1 = [
  {"song_id": 01, "artist_name": "Arijit, Shreya", "song_name": "Song1", "rating": 4},
  {"song_id": 02,"artist_name": "Jason, Ankit", "song_name": "Song2", "rating": 5},
  {"song_id": 03,"artist_name": "Asha, Lata, Bapi", "song_name": "Song3", "rating": 3},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can idea from here:

```js
let arr1 = [
  { song_id: 1, artist_name: 'Arijit, Shreya', song_name: 'Song1' },
  { song_id: 2, artist_name: 'Jason, Ankit', song_name: 'Song2' },
  { song_id: 3, artist_name: 'Asha, Lata, Bapi', song_name: 'Song3' },
];
let arr2 = [
  { song_id: 1, user_id: 5, rating: 4 },
  { song_id: 2, user_id: 5, rating: 5 },
  { song_id: 3, user_id: 5, rating: 3 },
];

arr1.map((item) => {
  let songID = item.song_id;
  arr2.map((item2) => {
    let songID2 = item2.song_id;
    if (songID === songID2) {
      item['rating'] = item2.rating;
      console.log(item);
    }
  });
});
```